# Remove '[]' and '()' from rows in a column

Tags: python, pandas, parentheses, brackets

I would like to remove the parentheses "(" and ")" and square brackets "[" and "]" from my rows in a data frame and split the values into two columns at the comma.

[image]

The desired output should be like on the image below.

[image]

Comment: Please [dont post pictures of your data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), we cannot copy and paste it. Provide a text version.

Comment: how did you read these rows? Maybe you should read them with different parameters. Or maybe you should write them in file in correct way.

Comment: @Erfan, kindly find the data below


([UBZ5678D], canter)
([UBZ5478D], drop sided)
([UBZ5278D], tipper)
([UBZ5178D], canter)
([UBZ5608D], tipper)


Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Suppose your DataFrame is named "df", we can get the series "my_data" and split it using the comma:

```
a = df["my_data"].str.split(",", expand=True)
```

Next is to iterate the columns inside the newly created Dataframe and remove all special characters from it using regex (**Note:** mine allows letters and numbers but you can modify it):

```
for i in a:
    a[i] = a[i].replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution lied in the data type. I converted the affected columns to string and just did a normal replace and it worked.